# How can i get any database structure into xml using one sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

please any body knows how can i get my database structure as xml

i have database : exdb 
i have table    : extbl1 
i have column   : excol1 
i have column   : excol2 
i have column   : excol3 
& have column   : excol4 
.... etc

how can i get the following structure

```
<DataBase DataBaseName="exdb">

 <Table TableName="extbl1">
  <Column ColumnName="excol1"/>
  <Column ColumnName="excol2"/>
  <Column ColumnName="excol3"/>
  <Column ColumnName="excol4"/>
 </Table>

 <Table TableName="extb2">
  <Column ColumnName="excol1"/>
  <Column ColumnName="excol2"/>
  <Column ColumnName="excol3"/>
  <Column ColumnName="excol4"/>
 </Table>

</DataBase>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for xml` and subqueries it is pretty simple:

```
select 
'exdb' [@DataBaseName],

(select t.table_name [@TableName],

 (select c.COLUMN_NAME [@ColumnName] 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
  for xml path('Column'), type)

 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
for xml path('Table'), type)

for xml path('DataBase')
```